# is there a way to integrate overlapped date intervals in r?

Tags: r

I'm trying to integrate/merge several overlapped intervals. And the following is an example of original dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                 degree=c(2,2,2,2),
                 start_date=c(as.Date("2010-01-20"),
                              as.Date("2010-01-25"),
                              as.Date("2010-03-20"),
                              as.Date("2010-03-25")),
                 stop_date= c(as.Date("2010-01-30"),
                              as.Date("2010-02-10"),
                              as.Date("2010-04-10"),
                              as.Date("2010-04-30")))
```

And here's the result I'm expecting:

```
df_result <- data.frame(id=c(1, 1),
                 degree=c(2,2),
                 start_date=c(as.Date("2010-01-20"),
                              as.Date("2010-03-20")),
                 stop_date= c(as.Date("2010-02-10"),
                              as.Date("2010-04-30")))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
df %>%
  arrange(start_date) %>%
  mutate(idx = stop_date > lead(start_date)) %>%
  mutate(stop_date = as.Date(ifelse(idx == TRUE, lead(stop_date), stop_date))) %>%
  filter(idx == TRUE) %>% select(-idx)

  id degree start_date  stop_date
1  1      2 2010-01-20 2010-02-10
2  1      2 2010-03-20 2010-04-30
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It shows error that I need to supply the origin

Comment: @rachel3765 Can you tell me in which line that error occurs?

Comment: It's on the forth row

Comment: @rachel3765 I'm sorry. You should use `zoo::as.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Group the data by id and degree and then create a vector of all dates between each start and stop, get the unique values among them and sort them giving `dates`.  Then  create a grouping variable `g` which keeps adjacent dates in the same group and summarize each group into a single row.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id, degree) %>%
  group_modify(~ with(., {
    dates <- sort(unique(do.call("c", Map(seq, start_date, stop_date, 1))))
    data.frame(dates, g = cumsum(c(TRUE, as.numeric(diff(dates)) != 1)))
  })) %>%
  group_by(g, .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarize(dates_start = min(dates), dates_stop = max(dates), .groups = "drop")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id degree     g dates_start dates_stop
  <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <date>      <date>    
1     1      2     1 2010-01-20  2010-02-10
2     1      2     2 2010-03-20  2010-04-30
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the solution! But when I apply the code to my original dataset, it shows the error: Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'sort': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'unique': error in evaluating the argument 'args' in selecting a method for function 'do.call': wrong sign in 'by' argument. I'm wondering if you have any idea about that. Thank you again!

Comment: I tried that, and it shows the error as: Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

Comment: My R Version is 4.1.0. I may need to update it first. And the code worked for the simplified example, but doesn't work in my original larger dataset.

Comment: It may be necessary to update but it may not be either. I suspect it is more likely that there are differences between the data you are using and what you posted in the question so you will need to either determine what is different  yourself since we don't have it or else create a small reproducible example that exhibits the problem and paste it at the end of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the lagged date differences, and rebuild the data frame on the subset and negated subsets, where they are negative.

```
s <- na.omit(with(df, c(FALSE, c(start_date[-1], NA) - stop_date) < 0))
res <- setNames(with(df, data.frame(id[s], degree[s], start_date[!s], stop_date[s])), 
                names(df))
res
#   id degree start_date  stop_date
# 1  1      2 2010-01-20 2010-02-10
# 2  1      2 2010-03-20 2010-04-30

stopifnot(identical(res, df_result))
```

This also works on multiple ID's as well as ID's with a single row, using `by`.

```
do.call(rbind, by(df2, df2$id, \(x) {
  if (nrow(x) > 1) {
    s <- na.omit(with(x, c(FALSE, c(start_date[-1], NA) - stop_date) < 0))
    setNames(with(x, data.frame(id[s], degree[s], start_date[!s], stop_date[s])), 
             names(x))
  } else {
    x
  }
}))

#     id degree start_date  stop_date
# 1.1  1      2 2010-01-20 2010-02-10
# 1.2  1      2 2010-03-20 2010-04-30
# 2.1  2      2 2010-01-20 2010-02-10
# 2.2  2      2 2010-03-20 2010-04-30
# 3    3      2 2010-03-25 2010-04-30
```

---

*Data:*

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), degree = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), start_date = structure(c(14629, 
14634, 14688, 14693, 14629, 14634, 14688, 14693, 14693), class = "Date"), 
    stop_date = structure(c(14639, 14650, 14709, 14729, 14639, 
    14650, 14709, 14729, 14729), class = "Date")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! But the system shows the error: Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [4]

Comment: @rachel3765 What happens if you leave out the renaming, i.e. just doing `with(df, data.frame(id[s], degree[s], start_date[!s], stop_date[s]))`?

Comment: it shows: Error in data.frame(patno[s], toxdeg[s], start_day[!s], stop_day[s]) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 5. So the problem is that the number of start and stop dates are different? And btw, I'm using the second method you applied.

Comment: @rachel3765 I guess there might be a special case if you split by id, just one row for instance. What does the respective check yield, `any(lengths(split(df2$id, df2$id)) == 1)`?

Comment: Yes, it returns "TRUE". And I believe that there are quiet amount of them have just one row.

Comment: And I just filtered the rows with more than one rows per id and degree, the error changed to: Error in data.frame(patno[s], toxdeg[s], start_day[!s], stop_day[s]) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 5. I double checked row 3 and 5, and I found that they are two time intervals do not overlap/intersect/consecutive

Comment: @rachel3765 Great, so a simple `if else` clause should fix it, please see updated second version if it works for you.

Comment: @rachel3765 Just saw your newer comment, I see...

Comment: @rachel3765 Could you provide such an example with two time intervals do not overlap/intersect/consecutive?